# svn branch to branch merge

Tags: svn, svn-reintegrate

I have a question about when to use `--reintegrate`. We created a branch called `Beta1` that we are using as a temp trunk for now while we try some new changes. Each developer then has a branch that they are making changes in. As necessary we are merging back to `Beta1` to test our changes. Should we be using `--reintegrate` when we merge from the `developer branch` to `Beta1` or just when we finally do `Beta1` to `trunk`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you merge Beta1 to trunk.

The [tortoise svn](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html) documentation is the 'best' (I use 'best' advisedly) explanation I could find. If you have a branch that has been kept up to date with changes made on trunk, reintegrate is used to merge the branch back to trunk; it does some additional checks to ensure that the branch contains any changes made to trunk since its creation.

In your example, this would mean that if Beta1 contains any changes made to trunk since they diverged, --reintegrate will instruct subversion that it's only merging changes that NEW to the Beta1 branch.

Comment: Right. But what about merging our dev branches into the Beta1 branch. Do we need to use reintegrate there?

Comment: You need to use reintegrate whenever changes on the destination you're merging TO have been applied to where you're merging FROM. If your changes are one way (i.e. dev -> beta1 -> trunk) you shouldn't need --reintegrate at all. If you merge dev -> beta1 -> dev, then you will need it. Look at it as a warning that 'there are incoming changes you already have'.